# getting values stored in a text file and turning them into variables

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
0_1 100 102 20 278 28 32 20 102 0_2 823 72 182 182 938 2739 182 162 0_3 3873 1728
```

there is a pattern, 0_1, 0_2, 0_3, this goes on to 0_10, and perhaps higher (blocks of 9). I am looking to turn each number into a variable. i'm using the following code to do so (filename calc_.cmd):

```
for /F "tokens=%1-%2" %%a in (%4) do (
    set "tick_%3=%%a"
    set "val1_%3=%%b"
    set "val2_%3=%%c"
    set "val3_%3=%%d"
    set "val4_%3=%%e"
    set "val5_%3=%%f"
    set "val6_%3=%%g"
    set "val7_%3=%%h"
    set "val8_%3=%%i"
)
```

Executing it like this:

```
call calc_.cmd 1 9 1 %1
call calc_.cmd 10 18 2 %1
call calc_.cmd 19 27 3 %1
call calc_.cmd 28 36 4 %1
```

`%1` being the text file. Moving on..

`echo %val8_1%` returns: `102`. but `echo %val8_4%` returns `ECHO is on.`

I'm assuming this has something to do with the range not being able to go higher than `26`, however `%val8_3%` does return it's correct value. I was wondering if there is another way to get around this, or maybe i'm doing it wrong, i'll be happy to hear! cheers

Comment: The [limit is 31](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/clevertricks.php#FORListExtended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification of your problem is somewhat confusing... Anyway, here it is a posible solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem %1 = Number of starting element in input list (tick_%3) of group %3
rem %2 = Number of ending element in input list (val8_%3) of group %3
rem %3 = Group
rem %4 = Input file

set /A "start=%1-1, end=%2-%1, n=0"
for /F "delims=" %%a in (%4) do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      if !start! gtr 0 (
         set /A start-=1
      ) else if !n! leq %end% (
         if !n! equ 0 (
            set "tick_%3=%%b"
         ) else (
            set "val!n!_%3=%%b"
         )
         set /A n+=1
      )
   )
)

SET TICK
SET VAL
```

Output example:

```
> calc_.bat 1 9 1 file.txt
tick_1=0_1
val1_1=100
val2_1=102
val3_1=20
val4_1=278
val5_1=28
val6_1=32
val7_1=20
val8_1=102

> calc_.bat 10 18 2 file.txt
tick_2=0_2
val1_2=823
val2_2=72
val3_2=182
val4_2=182
val5_2=938
val6_2=2739
val7_2=182
val8_2=162
```

You should note that your input data is redundant. If the start and end elements are multiple of 9 and always depends on the number of group, then they are not required because they can be calculated from the group number. This point also allows a different and simpler method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem %1 = Group
rem %2 = Input file

for /F "delims=" %%a in (%2) do set "input=%%a"

for /L %%i in (2,1,%1) do for /F "tokens=1-9*" %%a in ("!input!") do set "input=%%j"

for /F "tokens=1-9" %%a in ("%input%") do (
    set "tick_%1=%%a"
    set "val1_%1=%%b"
    set "val2_%1=%%c"
    set "val3_%1=%%d"
    set "val4_%1=%%e"
    set "val5_%1=%%f"
    set "val6_%1=%%g"
    set "val7_%1=%%h"
    set "val8_%1=%%i"
)

SET TICK
SET VAL
```

Output example:

```
> calc_2.bat 1 file.txt
tick_1=0_1
val1_1=100
val2_1=102
val3_1=20
val4_1=278
val5_1=28
val6_1=32
val7_1=20
val8_1=102

> calc_2.bat 2 file.txt
tick_2=0_2
val1_2=823
val2_2=72
val3_2=182
val4_2=182
val5_2=938
val6_2=2739
val7_2=182
val8_2=162
```

Comment: Thank you! works like a charm, the second solution seems much more convenient